# r.js can't build because of ENOENT error...says it can't find ".bin/bower"

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

I'm trying to get r.js to optimize all my Require-related files but am getting an error.

My site is in a directory called "myCrazysite" and is structured like this :

(not all the files)

```
myCrazysite
  js/
    buildform.js
    search.js
    app.build.js
  vendor/
    jquery
r.js
```

app.build.js looks like this:

```
({
  appDir: "../",
  aseUrl: "js",
  optimize: "none",
  dir: "buildOut",
  modules: [
    {
        name: ["buildform", "search"]
    }
  ]
})
```

I'm going into js/ and running`node ../r.js -o app.build.js`. I've also globally installed the CLI tool with npm and run `r.js -o app.build.js` from same directory.

When I do either of these two things, I get the following error:

`ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/me/Sites/myCrazysite/node_modules/.bin/bower'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:684:18)`

The steps I've taken are:

- navigated to to the above mentioned ".bin" directory on the CLI..the
  bower directory is there.
- upgraded to node v0.10.18
- uninstalled & reinstalled bower
- uninstalled the CLI tool and run `node ../r.js -o
  app.build.js`
- globally reinstalled the CLI tool back, deleted r.js
  from the site root, navigated to js/ and run `r.js -o app.build.js`

I'm using require v.2.1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind...I figured it out.

The issue was that the `.bin/bower` file was causing some conflict and just needed to be deleted. It was a stray shortcut file from (I think) a bower-related grunt plugin. As I wasn't using the plugin, I just used npm to uninstall it, then hard-deleted the file `.bin/bower.`

Moral of the story: the command line always tells you what to do...usually.